# replace a pattern with n number of spaces

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I am new to shell scripting, appreciate any help regarding below problem. I have tried to use **sed** and **awk** but unable to find a solution.

Problem: I have a fixed width file which has amount fields that need to be replaced with spaces/any special character like $ and the record length has to be maintained. The length of amount fields can vary.

For ex. if *sample_file.txt* has *record length of 10* and there are two amount fields starting at 2 and 6 of length 3 and 5 in this file as below:

> a234b67890

It has to be modified as:

> a$$$b$$$$$

This is for unix server.

**Edit:**

Also the records can have numeric characters at other positions which shouldn't be updated. So considering the previous example, the updated input is:

> a234b678901234567890

And new output should be:

> a$$$b$$$$$1234567890

Comment: *The records can have numeric characters at other positions which shouldn't be changed.* So how do you know what's a field you need changed and what needs to be left alone?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
inp=a234b67890
echo $inp | sed 's/[0-9]/$/g'
# gives a$$$b$$$$$
```

The only requirement is that the input should always be of *record_length* as sed replaces the numbers with the special character.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks foo. Apologies for not providing additional details. The records can have numeric characters at other positions which shouldn't be changed. Let me provide another example record of length 20 - a234b678901234567890. The amount fields starting at 2 and 6 only has to be changed to a$$$b$$$$$1234567890

Comment: @raghucn please update the question accordingly and include this example. If possible, provide details like what you have done so far.